# Why is there a last useless bin in d3js scaleTime histogram?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a list of dates and i tried to have bins representing each days of the week, in order to plot an histogram.
The result is somewhat what i wanted, but the last bin have x0=x1, and thus will always be empty.
Why is the bin array of 8 elements while i wanted 7 ?

I tried to read the documentation but it seems there is the same issue in provided examples

Here is the code i used:

```js
  const monday = new Date(2021, 4, 3)  // Monday 3 May 2021, midnight
  const next_monday =  new Date(2021, 4, 10)

  const scale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([monday, next_monday])

  const bins = d3.histogram()
      .domain(scale.domain())
      .thresholds(scale.ticks(7))

  console.log(
      bins([
          new Date(2021, 4, 3, 15), // 15h, monday
          new Date(2021, 4, 9, 15) // 15h, sunday, end of week
      ])
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

What results looks like:

```
0: Array [ Date Mon May 03 2021 15:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale) ]
    x0: Date Mon May 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)
​​    x1: Date Tue May 04 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)
​​1: Array []
​2: Array []
​3: Array []
​4: Array []
​5: Array []
​6: Array [ Date Sun May 09 2021 15:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale) ]
​7: Array []
​​length: 0
​​    x0: Date Mon May 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)
​​    x1: Date Mon May 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)
    !!! x1=x0 !!! Why is this bin added ?
​​    <prototype>: Array []
​
length: 8
```

Comment: I suppose it's because you have 7 sequential time intervals - you need 8 time points around them (points = intervals + 1)

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Well, i have 8 time points, `scale.ticks(7)` is returning an array of 8 elements. Suppose pipes | are time points and number the bins, bins() sould return something like this: `| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |` there is 8 time point and 7 bins. But in the results i obtainend with d3, i have 8 time points and 8 bins, wich is strange.

Answer (score 1):

> I have 8 time points, scale.ticks(7) is returning an array of 8 elements.

scale.ticks(7) doesn't necessarily return an array with 7 ticks: "The specified count is only a hint; the scale may return more or fewer values depending on the domain." [from the docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#time_ticks). The scale prioritizes "sensible values (such as every day at midnight)"

That midnight part is throwing off your ticks: it's a natural spot for a tick giving you 8 ticks, one on each Monday. Instead you can modify your domain so that you avoid that issue:

```
 const next_monday =  new Date(2021, 4, 10)-1  // just before midnight.
```

Ticks are guaranteed to be within the domain, so you shouldn't see that tick:

```js
const monday = new Date(2021, 4, 3)  // Monday 3 May 2021, midnight
  const next_monday =  new Date(2021, 4, 10)-1

  const scale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([monday, next_monday])

  const bins = d3.histogram()
      .domain(scale.domain())
      .thresholds(scale.ticks(7))

  console.log(
      bins([
          new Date(2021, 4, 3, 15), // 15h, monday
          new Date(2021, 4, 9, 15) // 15h, sunday, end of week
      ])
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I thought having 8 ticks was the desired output, as it made sens to have time points = (interval + 1). Anyway, i think writting sunday 23h, 59, 59 instead of monday 00h 00 00 is kind of ugly and error prone (no offence) so as an hotfix for now i have `const ticks = scale.ticks(7); ticks.pop()` as thresholds input, and then it works with clean dates, but still not very straightforward